# Decompile a win32-virus-executable on linux

Tags: linux, exe, decompiling, virus

How can I decompile a win32 x68 executable with ubuntu linux 32 bit?

I worked on Windows with IDA Pro, but as this is a windows-virus I cannot do this on my windows-machine.

Edit: Please name me an application for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDA is [available on Linux](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml), and can disassemble Windows files just fine.

Comment: Is IDA for Linux also available as a free version?

Comment: No, freeware version is only available for Windows right now. However, it seems it can [run under Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=23368) just fine. [The demo](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_demo.shtml) of the latest version is available for all three platforms.

Comment: Sadly, the Windows-version does not run with win. However, I'll use the demo version. Thank you!